# if executes when bool variable is false, in multithread senario

Tags: c++, multithreading, data-race

I'm working on a project, and encountered this weired problem. A detached threaded is used, and the stop flag is a boolen variable inside a structure which is passed by pointer of pointer(due to project needed). a simplified code  that can produce the problem  is attached here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
struct weired
{
    bool flag;
};

void hello_thread(void** stop)
{
    weired* c = (weired*)*stop;

    while (!(c->flag)) {

        if (c->flag)
        {
            std::cout << "weired happened!,  c->flag value is " << c->flag << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "thread released" << std::endl;


}

int open(void** handle)
{
    *handle = new weired;
    weired* a = (weired*)*handle;
    a->flag = false;
    std::thread t(hello_thread, handle);
    t.detach();
    return 0;
}

int  close(void** handle)
{
    weired* a = (weired*)*handle;
    a->flag = true;
    delete a;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    void* handle;
    n = open(&handle);

    std::cin >> n;

    n = close(&handle);


    return 0;
}
```

The cin in main funciton is for waiting purpose, and when the problem happened I don't input anything, so main fucntion just stuck at cin, just before calling close() function, so the "a->flag = true;" is not executed. Considering that  "std::thread t" is created after "a->flag = false;" in open() function, so when the subthread starts to run, all flag should evaluate as false, right?

The problem i encoutered  is that, the subthread can enter while loop, seemed  that c->flag was false, but it could aslo enter if statement and the loop was breaked, then thread quited since loop was done, so c->flag seemed to be true? but when printed its value inside if statement, the printed value was 0, still seemed that  c->flag is false. then why if statement executed?
[weired behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJ6Ad.png)

the project is on Visual Studio Community 2019, version 16.11.29 , target is release Win32. when in debug mode, this problem doesn't happen.

i also tried the same code on linux with g++ 11.4.0. when with -O2, subthread quit at startup, seems c->flag evaluates to true. but with -O1, subthread doesn't quit.
[linux g++ behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waL4p.png)

so the compiler optimization causes this problem?  Can compiler optimizes the thread creating executed before  "a->flag = false; " ?  but why if statement behaves so weired?

I tried replace bool with atomic<bool> type, and in this simplified code it worked, but in the real project it didn't.

Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: "simplified code is here, which can't reproduce the problem, but domonstrate the code sequence the same as the real project." If it doesn't reproduce the problem, I'm not sure I can take your word that it actually is a valid simplification of the real code.

Comment: Anyway, you've identified that a data race is occurring. That indeed means that the behavior of the program is undefined. All bets are off! Don't expect any rhyme or reason to how undefined behavior actually shakes out. It might be interesting to look at why the atomic<bool> version isn't working, but that would be me imagining some hypothetical alteration of this code that already doesn't reproduce the actual problem...

Comment: What are (void**)., "C" style casts and unecessary new doing in  your C++ code? Also you should NEVER detach a thread that is just asking for race conditions at shutdown

Comment: Since you say the code you've shown doesn't exhibit the problem, we can only guess.   But, from the code shown, there are two obvious potential causes of undefined behaviour (1) `main()` passes `(void **)&a` and the thread does `c =(weired*) *stop` which won't even compile - but that suggests you may be messing up the casts and/or are dereferencing pointers incorrectly  (2)   Your code modifies `a->flag` in `main()` and accesses `<something>->flag` (where the `<something>` might also be munged, as per (1)) in the launched thread, without sequencing or synchronisation.

Comment: Hey guys, thank you for all your kind comments. I have edit the description, and a problem-reproducable code is attached here.  What i am curious now is that  would compiler optimizer the execution of  std::thread  construction before “a->flag = false;”？ seems that the reorder of execution can explain some aspects of this problem.

Comment: Why do you assume that the thread was executed before flag=false? It looks rather like flag=true was executed before cin. And there is no reason not to do it, I believe. The result of cin has no influence on the code which follows it, so the compiler optimised it.

Comment: @zvone it may be the situation. so i slightly change the close function, but still the same behavior.  image is here https://imgur.com/a/g8qVWwa

Answer (score 1):

Having std::atomic is not always the solution for all data race problems.

What I see in your code is there are lot of read/write concurrent operations on the bool variable where the state can change any time.

What you need is some kind of locking mechanism, guard the flow until you read/write is done.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!  I have edit the description, and a problem-reproducable code is attached here. What i am curious now is that would compiler optimizer the execution of std::thread construction before “a->flag = false;”？ seems that the reorder of execution can explain some aspects of this problem.